# Last command during poweroff

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, shutdown, power-off

I am writing some software to shutdown some external hardware wired into my control board. The catch is that I need to wait for the VERY end of the poweroff operation to send the signal (through a gpio output). I am weighing some options right now, but I am curious as to where I can see what the kernel actually does right before poweroff.

Is there a file somewhere that I can look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start at the function `kernel_power_off` in `kernel/reboot.c` and follow the code. The final power-off operations are very platform specific, so if you want to follow down to the bitter end, you'd need to figure out exactly which bits of arch-specific code you're using.

One simpler possibility for sending your signals is to register a `kmsg_dump` handler. The last thing `kernel_power_off` does before invoking the platform-specific power-off code is to execute `kmsg_dump(KMSG_DUMP_POWEROFF);`. (Just ignore any `kmsg_dump` calls other than that one.)